# Quintuplet over 3/16th

Tags: theory, notation, sheet-music, tuplet

For quintuplets over 4/16th notes I can use 16th note quintuplet. For quintuplets over 2/16th notes I can use 32nd note quintuplet.

Is there any notation for quintuplets over 3/16th notes?
Imagine having a transition for 13/16th and finish with a quintuplet.

To me, only the notation is interesting - whether I need to change the metric, tempo or is there something special. This is not a real music question - just digging a bit in the theory and could not find any resources on this.

[Reference for 32nd quintuplets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrTHG.png)

**Edit:** This is what I get after using MuseScore as recommended in the answers.
[image: Quintuplets]
Not quite sure about the second measure, where 6 notes are beamed together as quintuplet, but one of them is proper 16th note, and 5 are 5/3?

**Edit 2:** I have actually found notation for this on wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuplet.
There is notation as mentioned in the answer - section Counting. This is exactly what I was looking for - 5:3 above the quintuplet. Also thing called nested tuplets looks really interesting.

Comment: Not sure about the first measure in your example.  The first quintuplet looks as though it should take a whole crotchet (quarter note).  Then there is a 16th rest followed by 12 16ths.  Doesn't add up unless you regard the quintuplet as taking up 3 16ths but that is by no means clear.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but this is what the MuseScore gives. If there is any other notation to write - like 5/3, I'd like to see it. The same goes for 3/16 measure, where a 16th note quintuplet won't fit.

Comment: Related [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/82049/2600).

Comment: Second measure- definitely need a beam/bracket with 5:3 to make it clear the last printed 16th is a "regular" 16th note. I'd strongly recommend this for the first measure as well.

Comment: FWIW, unless this is Adagio or slower, the performer is not going to be able to play the six notes exactly in-time, nor will any audience be able to tell.  Beware of "what you imagine" vs. "what you can get"

Comment: Why isn't this 5 16ths and a 16th rest under a 6:4 tuplet? That would seem to be the straight forward way. I agree with Carl Witthoft. 5:3 for 3/4 of a beat followed by a straight 1/4 a beat won't be heard and probably won't be played.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, put in a "5:3" where the "5" would normally be in a quintuplet and everything will be unambiguous. Music notation software like Musescore supports this ratio tuplet notation.

I'd probably use a 16th note quintuplet (well, 5:3-plet) for this purpose.

(I ended up using a 16th note 9:8-plet in a transcription once.)