# was the 12/16 measure usual in the time of Bach?

Tags: notation, history, j-s-bach

We met today this work by Bach with this strange time - strange to me as I've never met before this meter. Of course it is possible ... but I ask if someone knows another composition with this meter, not only by Bach.

[How do I determine the time signature of a song?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/84356/how-do-i-determine-the-time-signature-of-a-song/84364?noredirect=1#comment140521_84364)

(my assumption was that it is a simple 2/4 **(ed. or better 4/8)** where Bach ignored to write the sign for triplets as this would be obvious for everyone ...)

But now I've found the copy of the manuscript from **Johann Christian Bach** who wrote the time 12/16 for this Gigue.

[image]

Comment: 2/4 or 2/8 works for me, but technically I suppose 12/16 is accurate. To someone like Bach, would it really make any difference to have it in 12/16? We are a little late to ask him though.

Comment: It‘s no difference to me. There are only 2 points: a) I haven‘t ever seen 12/16 time.  (obviously there are several by Bach and others!) b) the question (I‘ve added the link now) asking: what measure is this? could be answered as: **Gigue, 4/8 (triplets abbreviation, usual in the time of Bach).**

Answer (score 2):

I think it's rather more a 4/8 with triple subdivision than a 2/4 with sextuple subdivision, as seen for example in [Prelude 13 of WTC I](https://digital.staatsbibliothek-berlin.de/werkansicht?PPN=PPN813072212&PHYSID=PHYS_0049&DMDID=DMDLOG_0012).  Bach used it several times.  There's a [recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxVDxize73U) that appears to show that Buxtehude used it, though I couldn't find much more about this piece, let alone a score.  There's also a [web page](http://www.johncollinsworthing.org.uk/pachelbel1.shtml) mentioning Pachelbel's use of the meter.

It therefore appears that it was not unusual in Bach's day.

Comment: Actually I also meant 4/8 of course! Look my argumentation in the other link. https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/84356/how-do-i-determine-the-time-signature-of-a-song/84364?noredirect=1#comment140521_84364

Comment: The recording you linked is of BuxWV 271. The score is here: https://imslp.org/wiki/Trio_Sonata_in_G_major%2C_BuxWV_271_(Buxtehude%2C_Dietrich)